Coding for meta-analysis
When coding studies to be included in a meta-analysis (meta-regression) not all of them will have the same covariates. My question deals with the following situation.
One study has age and sex.
One study has age, sex, and exposure to an infectious disease.
Would it be incorrect to code the first one as "0" for exposure because it doesn't have the exposure variable, or should it be left as a missing variable?

Have you thought of using multiple imputation, assuming you have enough covariate information?

I had not, but that is a great suggestion.

I just got an answer to my question. The variable should be left as missing. I suspected that was the case but was unsure. Thank you to all concerned.
